# Why is the navigation page black after populating an object from a Json scan?

Tags: c#, json, object, maui, zxing.net

Good afternoon,

My first time posting after using this website for years, so I apologize for formatting and probably a dumb question I can't find the answer for... I am scanning a QR Code that contains the JSON format below and am trying to populate a "device details page" with the full object's data from the ZtdId value from the JSON received from the scanned code. The parameter passes along fine to the new page, but the screen will be black.

JSON Format:

```
{"Version":"1.0.0","Id":"5ca169f7-9e7b-4861-abf5-859cdb468f6e","ZtdId":"dfb0527f-64d1-4f78-85ff-50cd6fab7e6c","PKID":"","SerialNumber":"","SequenceBlockNumber":1,"TotalBlocks":1}
```

[Black navigated page example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC6Nz.png)

I have a separate collectionview page that navigates to the same "device details page" and works fine. I've tried quite a number of combinations from the code referenced below in the hyperlink and across the internet, though, I can't get the page to load at all. I realized later in my fumbling that it wasn't loading the object and placed an "if the serialnumber is blank.." operator to connect it to the data.

I've even tried passing it to a blank or about page and it loads the page fine...What am I doing wrong here? (I can confirm if I write in a bunch of Console.WriteLine entries I can expose all the fields of the device I'm trying to load from the scanned code.) I've tried going through the "Xanimals" and many other sample solutions, from the sample github repositories, but can't seem to identify why the page comes up black.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#pass-data

Scan Page relevant code:

```
    async void BarcodesDetected(object sender, BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var first = e.Results?.FirstOrDefault();
            if (first is not null)
            {
                Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
                {
                    barcodeGenerator.ClearValue(BarcodeGeneratorView.ValueProperty);
                    barcodeGenerator.Format = first.Format;
                    barcodeGenerator.Value = first.Value;
                });
            }
            string Json = JToken.Parse(e.Results[0].Value).ToString();
            Models.Device device = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Device>(Json);
            var navigationParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "Device", device }
            };
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"devicedetails", navigationParameters);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Device Detail Page relevant code:

```
        public Models.Device Device { get; private set; }

        public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
        {
            Device = query["Device"] as Models.Device;
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Device.SerialNumber))
            {
                Models.Device device = DeviceData.Devices.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ZtdId == Device.ZtdId);
                Device = device;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("Device");
        }
```

Device Example:

```
        public static IList<Models.Device> Devices { get; private set; }

        static DeviceData()
        {
            Devices = new List<Models.Device>
            {
                new Models.Device
                {
                    SerialNumber = "00-000001",
                    Manufacturer = "Dell, Inc.",
                    Model = "XPS 13 9360",
                    PurchaseOrderNumber = "",
                    GroupTag = "US-EST-001",
                    DeploymentProfile = "Hybrid AAD",
                    AddressableUserName = "Jane Doe",
                    UserPrincipalName = "janedoe@contoso.com",
                    ZtdId = "dfb0527f-64d1-4f78-85ff-50cd6fab7e6c",
                    AzureActiveDirectoryDeviceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    ManagedDeviceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting any exceptions?

Comment: first, I'd suggest creating a blank ContentPage with just a label and navigate to that after scanning.  That should help narrow down if the problem is in the page, the navigation, etc

Comment: (Thank you, Jason!) I've accepted this as an issue with the scanner application itself and am waiting for a stable release (since the version is still on preview.)